# MS Access Reports

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a database of meetings.  I can generate a report that sorts the actions by meeting but I would like to generate a separate report for each meeting.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Query in Access with a 'Where' clause that's set to something like [Enter the meeting number].  When running this query, Access will prompt for user input.  Then you can set a report's data source to that query, so when running the report, Access will prompt for a meeting number (ID).

Alternatively, you could create a form with some sort of selection interface for the user to pick a meeting, dynamincally update the query, and run the report.

The first approach is easier, the second approach is more usable.

Comment: I would say the first approach may be easier for the programmer, but harder for the user. In the long run, it seems to me that the second is easier for the programmer since she can use the report anywhere and print all records, or a filtered set by passing the appropriate argument in the DoCmd.OpenReport action.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to report on all the meetings in one run, but get a separate report for each meeting you could add a grouping header on the Meeting and set that section of the report to do a page break before the that section.